# How can i get the application code created by gst-launch or gstreamer pipeline editor?

Tags: c, linux, multimedia, gstreamer

see if i have made one application like below by gst-launch commnad

```
gst-launch -v filesrc location=ed_hd.mkv ! matroskademux ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

when ever i type this on my console application start to work but i want to see the source code of this pipeline created by this command.

**1> So is there any way so i get the created pipeline/application code ?**

see when ever we create any application we got one executable file so by running that we can run program.

**2>  so how can i get that executable file from application created by gst-launch or gstreamer pipeline editor ?**

Comment: if you know the gstreamer and do not understand my question then let me know....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact gst-launch doesnt create any sourecode if that was what you were assuming.

Instead it uses the gstreamer function gst-parse-launchv to create the pipeline from the string the user passed to gst-launch via the commandline.

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-launchv

So if you dont want to manually write down the sourcecode for constructing a gstreamer pipeline you are free to call this gstreamer function from your code and let it parse any arbitrary pipeline description that you would normally give to gst-launch on the commandline.